# Make ClojureScript compiler output multiple, independent .js files for use in Cypress

Tags: compilation, automated-tests, cypress, clojurescript, leiningen

I'm trying to set up Cypress tests written in ClojureScript for a project that uses `lein-cljsbuild`. Using the following configuration, I'm able to compile a single test namespace into a single `.js` file:

```
:cljsbuild
  {:builds [{:id "cypress"
             :source-paths ["test/cypress"]
             :compiler     {:optimizations :simple
                            :main          "specs.login-spec"
                            :output-to     "cypress/integration/login_spec.js"
                            :output-dir    "test-resources/cypress/js/build/"}}]}
```

The above works fine and executes in Cypress correctly.

Now I want to scale it. Here are my requirements:

- have multiple specs written in ClojureScript: `specs.login-spec`, `specs.shopping-cart-spec`, `specs.checkout-spec`, and so on (I expect to have tens of those).
- I want Cypress to recognize them as separate test suites (so that, for instance, I can execute them independently). This means each ClojureScript test namespace has to end up in a separate JS file that is standalone, i.e. doesn't depend on any other JS file.
- I want to be able to compile all specs reasonably fast.
- I want source watching to be available as it is with a simple setup, i.e. `lein cljsbuild auto …` should still work, and use incremental building.

**How do I accomplish that?**

The most naive approach would be to specify one build plan for each spec. But that would mean that for N specs, I'd need to run compilation N times. That would be very slow.

The only other idea that popped to my head was ClojureScript modules, but the following setup emits empty files:

```
{:id "cypress"
 :source-paths ["test/cypress"]
 :compiler {:optimizations :simple
            :output-dir    "test-resources/cypress/js/build/"
            :modules {:m1 {:output-to "cypress/integration/login_spec.js"
                           :entries #{"specs.login-spec"}}
                      :m2 {:output-to "cypress/integration/checkout_spec.js"
                           :entries #{"specs.checkout-spec"}}}}}
```

My spec files are very simple right now - and individually, they compile and run in Cypress just fine. Example:

```
(ns specs.login-spec
  (:require [tools.commands]
            [tools.interop :refer [cy describe it]]))

(describe "Lorem" (fn []
  (describe "Ipsum" (fn []
    (it "Blah!" (fn []
      (-> cy
        (.LogInAndNavigate)
        …)))))))
```

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: Not fully. I ended up programatically generating the `:modules` for the Cypress CLJS build based on a hardcoded llist of spec files. This way I get a JS file per one spec file. But I need to remember to change the hardcoded list anytime I add or remove a spec file.